# global section of a locally free sheaf

Tags: algebraic-geometry

This is from Hartshorne:

> Let $s\in \Gamma(X,\mathcal{E})$ be a global section of a locally free sheaf $\mathcal{E}$ of rank $r$ on $X$. Then $s$ defines a homomorphism from $\mathcal{O}_X$ to $\mathcal{E}$ by sending $1$ to $s$.

Can someone explain in more detail how this homomorphism should be defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever $(X, \mathcal{O}_X)$ is a ringed space and $\mathcal{F}$ is an $\mathcal{O}_X$-module, you can pick a global section $s \in \Gamma(X,\mathcal{F})$ to define the multiplication by $s$ morphism $s \colon \mathcal{O}_X \rightarrow \mathcal{F}$, $f \mapsto sf$. Concretely it is given by multiplying with the restriction of $s$, i.e. by $\left.s\right|_U \colon \Gamma(U,\mathcal{O}_X) \rightarrow \Gamma(U,\mathcal{F})$, $f \mapsto \left.s\right|_U \cdot f$ on the level of local sections.

On the other hand, a morphism $\mathcal{O}_X \rightarrow \mathcal{F}$ also determines such a global section, by taking the image of $1 \in \Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$.

Comment: So this have nothing to do with $\mathcal{E}$ being locally free...?

Comment: No, one does not need that to define the morphism itself. I guess Hartshorne wants to use the property of being locally free in what follows afterwards.